# to replace some characters using regex and preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is an array:

```
$results = ['Rs. 5000', 'रु 1,200रु 1,50020% off'];
```

and i want to replace each item by 5000 in first one and in second one i want to get 1200 replacing other characters?

please help me using preg_replace and regex code in php

I've tried with other php builtin functions

```
if(!empty($results)) {
      foreach ($results as $my_object) {
      $names[] =  preg_replace("/[^-0-9]+/", '', $my_object);
    }
    array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, $results);
 }
```

I would expect 5000 and 1200 so that i can compare them

Comment: Should the third items also be replaced? Is there any logic to it?

Comment: there is no third item. there are only two items.. second one is a little messy. because of it, problem occured

Comment: Can you update the array into php? Is `$result` the array that you are looping? Does is contain only strings? What does `$my_object->Price` look like?

Comment: I've edited the code @thefourthbid.. please check

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `[^-0-9]+` matches any character except a digit or a hyphen `-`

Perhaps for your example data, you could match 1+ times not a digit `\D+` or match digits with an optional part to match either a dot/comma and 1+ digits.

At the end assert that what is on the right is not any of the listed `[,.रु]` or the end of the string `$`.

I think you can omit the `array_multisort`

```
\D+|\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\b(?![,.रु]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IoAuKK/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/X8eNm)

For example:

```
$results = ['Rs. 5000', 'रु 1,200रु 1,50020% off'];

if(!empty($results)) {
    foreach ($results as $my_object) {
        $names[] =  preg_replace("/\D+|\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\b(?![,.रु]|$)/", '', $my_object);

    }
}


print_r($names);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5000
    [1] => 1200
)
```